# Update constraint inside layoutSubviews() of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I need to update a constraint's value inside a `UITableViewCell`, which should trigger resizing of the cell. I need to know the correct frame before I can update the constraint's value, however having my code inside `layoutSubviews()` does not resize the cell. The subview which has the constraint attached to it grows, but cell stays the same initial height, cutting off the view.

My setup for the purpose of demonstration is very simple, I have a single `UIView` pinned to the edges of the cell's `contentView`, and a height constraint added to it. I expect the cell to resize when the height constraint of the view is changed.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    heightConstraint.constant = 500
}
```

Any ideas on why this is not working?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple quirks with changing cell height in `layoutSubviews()`.

Typically, when a cell modifies its internal layout (constraints, etc), the cell must tell the table view to redraw itself.

In your case, the cell's `layoutSubviews()` is being called *after* the table view has determined the cell's height.

Couple ways around this, if you really do need to do that in `layoutSubviews()`:

1 - call relaodData() in `viewDidAppear()`

2 - force the cell layout inside `cellForRowAt`:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCell
    // set your cell properties here as usual - labels, images, etc...
    cell.setNeedsLayout()
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
    return cell
}
```